# I have a dataframe into my dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, extract

I have a dataframe in which it appears that i have another dataframe where the separator is comma and i don't know how to extract the inner dataframe. I tried to exctract only the column in question but when i open it using the comma as separator it doesn't work.

This is my main dataframe

```
data_sfr_trace = pd.read_csv('10_trace.csv',low_memory=False)
```

And this is what i did to extract body

```
body2 = data_sfr_trace['body']
body2.to_csv('body.csv')
```

And then i opened it using comma as a separator

```
body = pd.read_csv('body.csv',low_memory=False,header=None,sep=",")
```

As shown in the pictures i don't have body as a dataframe [main dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXu72.png) and [body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIZy3.png)

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: The object inside isn't a DataFrame. It is some sort of dictionary that you will need to parse.

Comment: I didn't think about that, i wil try to parse it then

Comment: Thx, i extracted that column and parsed it and it worked

Comment: Glad to hear it!